# Python and netCDF sciprt do not operate anymore

Tags: variables, python-2.6, netcdf

I am using a python 2.6 script, that I have been using for quite a while now and I get an error that it shouldn't be there. The python script is run form the location of where the netCDF file is located, here is the code

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as numpy
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import datetime as DT
from time import strftime
import os

floc ='/media/USB-HDD/NCEP_NCAP data/data_2010/'   #location of directory that the file resides
fname ='cfsr_Scotland_2010'    # name of the netCDF file
in_ext = '.nc'        # ending extentsion of the netCDF

basetime = DT.datetime(2010,01,01,0,0,0)   # Initial time (start) for the netCDF

ncfile = Dataset(floc+fname+in_ext,'r')    # netCDF assigned name



time = ncfile.variables['time']
lon = ncfile.variables['lon'] 
lat = ncfile.variables['lat']
uwind = ncfile.variables['10u']  
vwind = ncfile.variables['10v']
ht = ncfile.variables['height']
```

I get the error in the ncfile naming, which is odd cause I checked the way its written

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CFSR2WIND.py", line 24, in <module>
    ncfile = Dataset(floc+fname+in_ext,'r')    # netCDF assigned name
  File "netCDF4.pyx", line 1317, in netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4.c:14608)
RuntimeError: No such file or directory
```

Does anybody know why and what caused this, and how can It be solved

thank you

george

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `netcdf` module from scipy instead:

```
from scipy.io.netcdf import netcdf_file as Dataset
```

Couple other suggestions:

1. Importing `numpy`. You're importing it twice, and it's a bit dangerous to read in all instances using `*`. By convention, most people abbreviate numpy as `np` and load it as `import numpy as np`. Then you can call instances from numpy using `np.mean()` for example.
2. Concatenating the path, filename, and file extension.  It's OK to use string concatenation using the `+` sign, but there is another way to do this using the `join` command. So, the total filename would be something like `filename = ''.join([floc, fname, in_ext])`.